# Google chrome default startup

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to get rid of "Most visited" and "Recently closed" links in chrome startup? I do not want to bother to clear the history each time. I just want it to not appear by defalt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a home page for the initial start of Chrome.  However, new tabs will still use the "new tab" page.

The [New Tab Redirect!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) extension for Chrome allows you to modify new tabs though.

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse the sections in the new-tab page by clicking the little triangles to the right of them.

You can also click the `☒` that appears when you hover the cursor over the items in the *Most visited* section.

Either way, hiding them doesn’t get rid of the history, for that you’ll need [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?category=ext&q=clear%20history) (or run in Incognito Mode).